# Incompatible pointer types warning with typedef and struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct {
        int pid;
        struct f_queue_node *next;
}f_queue_node;


typedef struct {
        f_queue_node *front, *rear;
}f_queue;

f_queue *queue;
f_queue_node *node 
queue->rear->next = node;
```

I get a warning whenever I use a pointer of f_queue_node with front and rear.

queue_f.c:39:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

queue->rear->next = node;
                     ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
typedef struct f_queue_node {
        int pid;
        struct f_queue_node *next;
} f_queue_node;
```

instead of:

```
typedef struct {
        int pid;
        struct f_queue_node *next;
} f_queue_node;
```

That's happens because of you `typedef` an anonymous `struct`.

Also, you miss semicolon here `f_queue_node *node`, I don't know if you miss it while posting it here or in your code, just a reminder.

Comment: Wow! That was a simple thing and I was breaking my head on it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `next` field of `f_queue_node` (a typedef for an anonymous struct) defined as a pointer to `struct f_queue_node`, but you don't have `struct f_queue_node` defined anywhere in your code.

You need to give that anonymous struct a tag:

```
typedef struct f_queue_node {
        int pid;
        struct f_queue_node *next;
}f_queue_node;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dbush. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer. I have accepted the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign node without alloc queue and node.

You have to alloc on the stack :

```
f_queue queue;
f_queue_node node 
queue.rear->next = &node;
```

or on the heap with malloc :

```
f_queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(f_queue));
f_queue_node *node = malloc(sizeof(f_queue_node));
queue->rear->next = node;
```